# Custom PHPUnit Constraint stopped working

Tags: php, phpunit

I've created myself a custom PHPUnit Constraint and connect it to a nice `assert...` function.

I slip it in in my base `TestCase`, it's the `assertLastError` function:

```
/**
 * abstract, base test-case class.
 */
abstract class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * assert lint of a php file
     */
    protected function assertLint($filename, $message = '') {
        self::assertThat($filename, new ConstraintLint, $message);
    }
    /**
     * assert the last error
     */
    protected function assertLastError($error, $file, $message = '') {
        self::assertThat($file, new ConstraintLastError($error), $message);
    }
    /**
     * assert XML DTD validity
     */
    protected function assertXmlStringValidatesDtdUri($xml, $dtd, $message = '') {
        self::assertThat($dtd, new ConstraintXmlStringValidatesDtdUri($xml), $message);
    }

    ...
```

I've debugged the constraint so far and I see that the `evaluate` method gets called and returns `FALSE`, however the testrunner does not report me a failure.

The constraint:

```
/**
 * ConstraintLastError
 *
 * For asserting the last error message in a file.
 *
 * To test trigger_error().
 *
 * Example:
 *
 *   $this->assertLastError('Error Message', 'basenameOfFile.php');
 *
 */
class ConstraintLastError extends \PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint {
    private $file;
    private $error;
    public function __construct($error) {
        $this->error = $error;
    }
    /**
     * Evaluates the constraint for parameter $file. Returns TRUE if the
     * constraint is met, FALSE otherwise.
     *
     * @param string $file Value or object to evaluate.
     * @return bool
     */
    public function evaluate($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $error = $this->error;
        $lastError = error_get_last();
        if (NULL === $lastError)
            return false;

        $last_message = $lastError['message'];
        $last_file = $lastError['file'];


        $result = ($error == $last_message && basename($file) == basename($last_file));

        var_dump($result, $error, $last_message, $file, $last_file);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed   $other
     * @param string  $description
     * @param boolean $not
     */
    protected function customFailureDescription($other, $description, $not)
    {
        return sprintf('Failed asserting that the last error %s', basename($other), $not ? '' : 'no ', implode("\n  - ", $this->lines));
    }


    /**
     * Returns a string representation of the constraint.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function toString()
    {
        return sprintf('was %s in file %s.', $this->error, $this->file);
    }
}
```

I have no clue why this stopped working, the testcase just finishes cleanly, I can see the error message in the output incl. stacktrace (xdebug is on) and the `var_dump` tells me the result is `FALSE`. Here is the test:

```
public function testGetType()
{
    ...

    $fragment->setParsed(array());
    \PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning::$enabled = FALSE;
    $actual = $fragment->getType();
    \PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning::$enabled = TRUE;
    $this->assertLastError('Invalid State Error FAIL', 'Fragment.php');
}
```

This is a new test I just wrote, I have the same assertion in other places as well and they don't work any longer as well.

PHPUnit 3.6.7

Comment: did you set a custom error handler (set_error_handler) in your code? was xdebug enabled when it worked?

Comment: no custom error handler (in my code). I don't remember if xdebug was enabled when it worked. I deactivated the xdebug deactivation of earlier PHPUnit versions manually and by default on my dev xdebug is on. So it's likely that xdebug was enabled when it worked, but I do not specifically remember. I have somehow the feeling I'm paying the price to not put my constraints under test.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is triggered in the first place? What happens if you don't disable PHPUnit's warning-to-exception conversion?

Comment: If I enable it, PHPUnit reports the error. FAILURES! Tests: 4, Assertions: 5, Errors: 1. Disabled: OK (4 tests, 6 assertions) - The assertion is counted but passes even if evaluate returns FALSE.

Comment: I wonder how I can track a PHPUnit session with a remote/step debugger.

Comment: @hakre You can start `php -d xdebug.enable=1 /path/to/phpunit.php` like any other cli script you want to debug. Nothing in PHPUnit should interfere with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve this now. This is related to me having upgraded PHPUnit, the API changed slightly. I've taken `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint` as the pattern for my own constraint again, reading the comments in there helps.

The `evaluate` function differs now, I've moved the evaluation logic now into a private function and switched from `evaluate` to `matches`. It works with the return value. `evaluate` does not work with the return value by default any longer but expects throwing an exception. To fully benefit from that, you can also instantiate some comparator object but that was over my head, you can find more info about that in the `asserEquals` constraint.

```
class ConstraintLastError extends \PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint {

    ...

    /**
     * Evaluates the constraint for parameter $file. Returns TRUE if the
     * constraint is met, FALSE otherwise.
     *
     * This method can be overridden to implement the evaluation algorithm.
     *
     * @param mixed $other Value or object to evaluate.
     * @return bool
     */
    public function matches($file)
    {       
        return $this->compareAgainstLast($file, $this->error);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param string $file
     * @param string $error
     * @return bool
     */
    private function compareAgainstLast($file, $error)
    {
        if (!$last = error_get_last())
        {
            $last = array('message' => '(none)', 'file' => '');
        }

        $this->lastError = $last['message'];
        $this->lastFile  = $last['file'];

        return $error === $this->lastError && basename($file) === basename($this->lastFile);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $file
     */
    protected function failureDescription($file)
    {
        return sprintf('the last error is "%s" in %s, was "%s" in %s'
                    , $this->error, basename($file)
                    , $this->lastError, basename($this->lastFile)
                );
    }

    ...
```

It now works like a charm:

```
1) FragmentTest::testGetType
Failed asserting that the last error is "Suboptimal State Error" in Fragment.php, was "Invalid State Error" in Fragment.php.
```

Others had similar problems but a different solution switching to `fail` which you can call as well because it's implemented in the base class [Phake Fixes issues #43 and #44](https://github.com/mlively/Phake/commit/6dfd309c782a86db0138a74587c4b2d7e3651712).

Comment: Looks good to me. ->fail is also used in some of phpunits own contraints by the way: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Framework/Constraint/IsIdentical.php - The comparator is mostly useful for getting PHPs `==` behavior straight ( see: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.6/PHPUnit/Framework/Constraint/IsEqual.php ) but is not needed in your case. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: @edorian: Thank you for the feedback. Do you think it's worth to suggest such an assertion to PHPUnit? (I already modified it a bit so it's more useful, e.g. filename optional, more focus on the actual error message).

Comment: I don't think soa as leaving PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warning::$enabled on and `* @expectedException PHPUnit_Framework_Error_Warnings * @expectExceptionMessage myExcpetedErrorMessage` is whats recommendend for those cases and giving users another option is not worth the extra complexity as not many people really should need it. I can definitely see your use case but I don't think it applies to many people. Might be wrong though.. it's always to judge for everyone :) Maybe there should be a poll at some time with suggestions :)